# Generate many other individual mono out of one originating mono with R2DBC and Reactor

Tags: project-reactor, reactor, r2dbc

I created a database sequence with an increment of 5, allowing me to reserve a range of values in memory, and dividing my number of access to the database by 5. ( my real life case is 100000 values)

My R2DBC service will call R2DBC API and do a query that returns a long in a mono.

```java
public class SequenceService {
   public Mono<Long> nextVal() {
      return r2dbc.query("select nextval('mysequence')");
   }
}
```

let's say we call this service in a test

```java
   sequenceService = new SequenceService( ... );

   assertTrue(sequenceService.nextVal().block() == 10L);
   assertTrue(sequenceService.nextVal().block() == 15L);
   assertTrue(sequenceService.nextVal().block() == 20L);
```

What I want to do is that my nextVal call could fill up in between values, so as

```java
   assertTrue(sequenceService().nextVal().block() == 10L);
   assertTrue(sequenceService().nextVal().block() == 11L);
   assertTrue(sequenceService().nextVal().block() == 12L);
   assertTrue(sequenceService().nextVal().block() == 13L);
   assertTrue(sequenceService().nextVal().block() == 14L);
   assertTrue(sequenceService().nextVal().block() == 15L);
   assertTrue(sequenceService().nextVal().block() == 16L);
   assertTrue(sequenceService().nextVal().block() == 17L);
   assertTrue(sequenceService().nextVal().block() == 18L);
   assertTrue(sequenceService().nextVal().block() == 19L);
   assertTrue(sequenceService().nextVal().block() == 20L);
```

Coding it just like below doesn't work because you would always get "n+0", and never "n+1", "n+2", "n+3", "n+4" :

```java
public class SequenceService {

    public Mono<Long> nextVal() {
        return r2dbc.query("select nextval('mysequence')")
                        .map(n -> Flux.range(0,5)).map(i -> n + i)).repeat().next();
        }
}
```

I don't see how I can generate many other individual mono out of one originating mono.

I must preserve some kind of state, of the flux, of the current sequence value, but don't see how to do it.

Comment: your explanation of your problem is not very clear, `I had a working solution in JDBC` where is the code for that solution? `I tried to use shareNext() share() repeat()` where is the code? and why did it not work? `I also tried using a field with a AtomicReference<Mono>` where is this code? `But I fail to have something that works` this is not helpful, what is failing more exact. Not only "it is failing". `it didn't made much sense to do that.` what did not make sense to do what?

Comment: I cleaned the post and prefer forget about existing code and start over by using reactor concepts right.

Comment: you are approaching this in an imperative way. That Flux is a sort of list, which it isnt. Its something that you subscribe to and it will give you values when it has them, and when it runs out of items, the subscription ends. I cant write you a code example since i still dont really understand what you want but i think you should generate your sequence using https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing.generate

Comment: My source of data is Mono<Long> obtained by a r2dbc query. I cannot use Flux.generate with that.

Comment: please provide a working example to demonstrate your problem, right now your code is including mostly calls to unknow apis for instance `sequenceDao.getSequenceIncrement` `sequenceDao.nextVal("mysequence")` `sequenceDao.getIncrement("mysequence")` and `SequenceState.builder().dbSeq(seq).increment(inc).virtual(seq).build()` so as mentioned, your explanation is not clear and all the code you have provided is non runnable. If you have problems please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example good luck

Comment: I don't ask for someone to debug my code. Reactor as some concepts, and with what I exposed it should be feasible to conclude how to do it in the abstract. As I said I use r2dbc to query a database sequence.

Comment: well to me your question is not clear, and without a running example then i wont be able to help you, as i still dont understand what it is you want to do and if you refuse to provide more clarity, then Good luck

Comment: As I said I am not reporting a bug.

Comment: So I did my best to explain with a unit test usage exemple.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to create a Flux that will generate the next value, similarly as you did:

```java
    r2dbc.query("select nextval('mysequence')")
        .flatMapMany(next -> Flux.range(0, 5).map(n -> next + n))
        .repeat()
```

Then subscribe to this flux immediately, with a custom subscriber that will request the next value on demand using the method `request(1)` each time you need the next value.

However, because your method `nextVal()` may be invoked concurrently, you need a mechanism such as a waiting list.

Here is a full example:

```java
public class SequenceService {
        
    private Subscription subscription;
    private LinkedList<MonoSink<Long>> waitingList = new LinkedList<>();
    private Throwable error;
        
    public SequenceService() {
        r2dbc.query("select nextval('mysequence')")
            .flatMapMany(next -> Flux.range(0, 5).map(n -> next + n))
            .repeat()
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                    subscription = s;
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onNext(Long val) {
                    boolean needRequest;
                    MonoSink<Long> sink;
                    synchronized (waitingList) {
                        sink = waitingList.poll();
                        needRequest = !waitingList.isEmpty();
                    }
                    if (sink != null) {
                        sink.success(val);
                    }
                    if (needRequest)
                        subscription.request(1);
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    error = t;
                    synchronized (waitingList) {
                        MonoSink<Long> sink;
                        while ((sink = waitingList.poll()) != null)
                            sink.error(t);
                    }
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                }
            });
    }
    
    public Mono<Long> nextVal() {
        return Mono.create(sink -> {
            boolean needRequest;
            synchronized (waitingList) {
                if (error != null) {
                    sink.error(error);
                    return;
                }
                waitingList.push(sink);
                needRequest = waitingList.size() == 1;
            }
            if (needRequest)
                subscription.request(1);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I didn't expected it would have to be so complicated. Too bad there isn't some prexisting construct to do that. I don't understand yet whay a sink is, I could do without this so far.

Comment: I implemented it but it goes into out of memory in the case of parallel consumming of the nextVal() function. I tried to make it safer, but it's too slow for what it's supposed to be doing.